Is it safe to delete \ProgramData\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Log folder?
I ask because in event viewer I'm getting this error:
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume C:.
The Master File Table (MFT) contains a corrupted file record.  The file reference number is 0x117000000004546.  The name of the file is "\ProgramData\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Log\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.log".

It’s a log file. It will just get recreated when deleted. Your drive is failing that’s why a problem with your MFT has been discovered. Does not really matter if it’s safe or not the file is corrupted and has already essentially been deleted

It is safe to delete.  A corrupt file table record doesn't necessarily mean drive failure.  You are running more of a risk of getting crosslinked files, so backup would be a good idea.
